# Visual studio Xamarin Android SDK

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 professional, including Mobile development with .NET.

When I create a Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Formsapp (master detail, PCL), I am able to launch this with emulator Visualstudio_android-23_arm_phone (Android 6.0 - API level 23), however I get a warning: non-(x86) android emulator is 10 times faster and indeed, it is slow.

I also get $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (v7.0) is greater than $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0), while I didn't change anything from the template, not sure if it matters though?

I tried to download a different android emulator: Marshmallow (API level 23), but now I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in my output.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong (plain install, plain template), how should I get rid of all those warnings and what Emulator should I use?

Answer (score 0):

**Visualstudio_android-23_arm_phone (Android 6.0 - API level 23)** is an arm emulator - so a different chipset to what you have on your PC. This means it will have to emulate the hardware layer which makes it slower.

There should be an emulator with x86 in the name (and probably with accelerated in the name as well), so use that one.